# Computed property not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

I have a weird problem. I'm trying do to a simple time tracking app.

So I have this form.

```
<form class="form" @submit.prevent="saveHours">
    <div class="status">
        <div class="selector" v-for="(select, index) in select_all">
            <component :is="select" :id="index" @percentage="trackTime"></component>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.status -->
    <div class="form-submit">
        <button type="submit" class="form__submit">
            <span v-if="loading">Guardando...</span>
            <span v-else>Guardar</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my vue code

```
export default {
    name: 'home',
    data() {
        return {
            select_all: [Selector],
            loading: false,
            allTimes: [],
            saveForm: []
        }
    },
    components: {
        Selector
    },
    computed: {
        calculateTotal() {
            return this.allTimes.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => parseInt(accumulator) + parseInt(currentValue), 0);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addNewSelector() {
            this.calcTotal();
            this.select_all.push(Selector)
        },
        trackTime(time, index, proyecto) {
            this.currentTime = time;
            this.allTimes[index] = time;

            const data = {
                time,
                proyecto
            }

            this.saveForm[index] = data;
        },
        saveHours() {
            const currentWeek = moment(new Date()).format('w');
            const diverRef = db.collection('divers').doc(firebaseAuth.currentUser.email);
            const currentWeekRef = diverRef.collection('reportes').doc(`semana_${currentWeek}`);
            var self = this;
            currentWeekRef.get().then(function(doc) {
                if ( doc.exists ) {
                    console.log('Ya registraste tus horas');
                } else {
                    currentWeekRef.set({
                        data: self.saveForm
                    })
                }
            });
        },
    }
}
```

I have a component called , what I do is that when someone types the number of hours, I emit that time back to the parent and use the `trackTime` function to add the time of each project to the `allTimes` array.

I'm trying to use a computed property `calculateTotal` to add the times together so I know when a user completed the 100% of hours. But is not updating.

Is really weird, if I use it as a method it works like a charm, but it doesn't work for me because i want it to update as the user is typing and since I'm using a component for the input I can't use `keyup` events.

I've been trying to figure this out for hours now and nothing. Thanks!

Comment: Your computed depends on `allTimes`. You're modifying it by `this.allTimes[index] = time;`. But you cannot do that, vue reactivity breaks if you modify an array by index: https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is having the same problem Sergeon and Roy J where right.

I was doing this

```
this.allTimes[index] = time;
```

And that was messing up Vue. I changed the code to

```
this.allTimes.splice(index, 1, time)
```

And it works perfect now.

Thanks